# Type error when importing vendored package

Tags: go, vendor

I am currently trying to export all shared components from multiple services to one new package and then reimporting this package to the services.

I quickly came accross the following problem:
In my utility package I create a function:

```
package utils

import "github.com/rs/zerolog"
func CreateLogger(logLevel string, w io.Writer) Logger {
    ...
    return zerolog.New(w).With().Timestamp().Logger()
}
```

So now this package references `"github.com/rs/zerolog"`

Now in my services I want to use this method like this:

```
import "github.com/rs/zerolog"
var (
    logger      zerolog.Logger
)

func New() {
    logger = utils.CreateLogger("info", os.Stdout)
}
```

Now this also references `"github.com/rs/zerolog"`, but throws the error:

`cannot use utils.CreateLogger("info", os.Stdout) (type "MY_REPO_PATH/vendor/VENDORED_REPO_PATH/vendor/github.com/rs/zerolog".Logger) as type "MY_REPO_PATH/vendor/github.com/rs/zerolog".Logger in assignment`

So I understand why this is happening and I found a solution by wrapping the zerologger in my utils into a struct like this:

```
type Logger struct {
    Logger zerolog.Logger
}
```

Now this works, but it is inconvenient because I have to call `logger.Logger.Info()...` instead of `logger.Info()` in my code.

It looks to me like this is not the perfect solution to this problem and I would like to know if there is a better way to solve it.

Best Regards,
Jonathan

Comment: You can't have nested vendor directories. Your vendoring tool should take care of this for you.

Comment: Could you explain on how to solve this problem? I don't quite understand how a vendoring tool like "dep" can resolve this problem

Comment: Because you never want nested vendor directories, the various vendoring tools will strip these out, and may even hoist the same dependencies up into the top level `vendor/` directory for you.

Comment: Basic solution is to move everything from `MY_REPO_PATH/vendor/VENDORED_REPO_PATH/vendor/` to `MY_REPO_PATH/vendor/`, then delete the former (the vendor folder only).  Vendoring tools will generally do this for you, but if you're using manual vendoring for some reason, that's how you solve it.  This is called "flattening" your vendor dependencies.

Comment: Also, incidentally, for your struct, if you _embed_ the logger (ie. `type Logger struct { zerolog.Logger }` instead of `type Logger struct { Logger zerolog.Logger }`), you'd be able to call `logger.Info()` directly as well.

Comment: Thank you for all this insight, I am relatively new to Go and especially vendoring is giving me strungle.